# How to make multiple queries filters in graphene flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python

I'm a relative newcomer to GraphQL, I'm trying to make a query like this

```
{
   user(username: "Jon") { 
     name
     last_lame
     username
     posts(in_draft : true) { 
       title
       text
       in_draft
       update_at      
     }
   }
}
```

I want to filter the list of posts that the user has in draft

The only way I can do the query is through the relationship of the models, but without being able to filter in the posts in draft.
One to many

```
class User(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'user'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String)
  last_lame = Column(String)
  username = Column(String)


class Post(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'post'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = Column(String)
  text = Column(String)
  in_draft = Column(Boolean) 
  post_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))

  posts = relationship("User", backref='posts')
```

With this relationship, I show the posts node with "backref = 'posts'"

My objects:

```
class User(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
  """User Object."""
  class Meta:
    model = UserModel
    interfaces = (relay.Node, )


class Post(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
  """Post Object."""
   class Meta:
      model = PostModel
      # interfaces = (relay.Node, )
```

Query:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):

    user = graphene.Field(lambda: User, username=graphene.String())
    def resolve_user(self, info, username):
       query = User.get_query(info)
       return query.filter(UserModel.username == username).first()
```

I want to make the query of the posts belong to the user

```
   posts = graphene.List(lambda: Post, in_draft=graphene.Boolean())
   def resolve_posts(self, info, in_draft):
      query = Post.get_query(info)
      return query.filter(PostModel.in_draft == in_draft).all()

schema = graphene.Schema(
   query=Query,
   types=[User, Post])
```

Any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Honestly, given that the relationship between `User` and `Post` is already defined I would create a single resolver to get those combined results passing the two arguments at once like this:

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    filter_user_posts = graphene.List(
        lambda: User,
        username=graphene.String,
        in_draft=graphene.Boolean,
    )
    def resolve_filter_user_posts(
        self, info, username, in_draft
    ):
        query = User.get_query(info=info)
        query = query.join(User.posts)
        query = query.filter(User.username == username)
        query = query.filter(Post.in_draft == in_draft)

        objs = query.all()

        return objs
```

which you can then simply query like this:

```
{
 filterUserPosts(username: "Jon", in_draft: true) { 
   name
   last_lame
   username
   posts{ 
     title
     text
     in_draft
     update_at      
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Works for me but one small correction or clarification. in filter_user_posts . the line should be username=graphene.String(). String is a class